# compare two binary files

Tags: assembly, binary, diff, decompiling, objdump

How do I diff two binary files?

I have two versions of a program, version 1 and version 2. I've made a small number of changes between the two version, but unfortunately haven't been backing up regularly, and so although I've got the source for version 2, I only have the binary of version 1. I need to find out what, exactly, I changed between the two versions. I've tried creating an objdump of the two versions and then using diff to find the changes, but that doesn't work because the offsets are different, and so diff considers almost every line to have changed.

For example, one line might be `bgez v0,4074d0<daemonize+0xd4>` in version 1, and `bgez v0,4073d4<daemonize+0xd4>` in version 2. These are copied directly from the dump files - you can see the two lines do the same thing, but diff can't distinguish them. The files are too big for me to examine every line manually; How do I detect functionality changes, while ignoring differences in offset?

Comment: This sounds like a real-world NP-complete problem. ;-)

Comment: Not NP-complete, because it can be solved by a DFA.

Comment: What NP and DFA means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually solved this by removing the raw instructions and offset markers so I only had the assembly, then using sed to strip out every digit, and filtering diff to ignore changes consisting of only 1 line. I was a little surprised that it worked, but it did.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. I am currently working on a project that is capable of searching function and memory pointer addresses from a compiled file within a new/modified binary file. It supports windows PE and ELF binaries on x86 and x86_64. There is also a paper describing the approach. It works good for my reversing project, where I have to update all hooks and memory addresses frequently when binary updates are made. But there are other use-cases as well.

[Check it out here.](http://duschkumpane.org/index.php/asmdiff)

The trick is that it does not rely on weak text comparisons, it disassembles the binaries and compares all functions by measuring the geometric distance between them using code metrics.

Comment: Any chance that asmDIFF will be published in a standalone form? From what I can see, asm_hint_C and asm_search_C are pretty tightly coupled into mmBBQ and lua... Which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but makes it hard to be used standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: write your own diff that can ignore one or either of the operands of the opcodes if they are a numerical immediate value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed or awk (or perl or...) to write a filter to make all the offsets identical before running diff.  Writing such a filter is left as an exercise to the reader. :-P

Comment: You have answered the question 'How do I do it' by saying 'it can be done'. While technically correct, this is completely useless. -1

Answer (score 0):

Sure something like [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) would do the job?

Comment: I'm trying to find what's changed between the two programs - I might be using it wrong, but bsdiff doesn't seem very helpful. How would you do it?

Comment: @Benubird: bsdiff makes binary differentials on a code level, not a byte level, chrome courgette took this one step farther by adding(well removing) relocatable jumps/offsets from the differentials, leaving behind on the code section that really changed, not just shifted. think of it link diff & patch but on the assembly level instead of text level